# Why does this script work in Chrome but not in Firefox?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox

I have this script, but it only works in Chrome. What might be the issue for not working in Firefox?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $('form').submit(function() {
        $.post('/parts', function() {
            window.location = '/parts';
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: what exactly is not working on Firefox ?

Comment: It only post submit button, but doesn't open new location "/part"

Comment: What your code tries to do is post to a URL, and then when the response is received issue a GET to the exact same URL. That doesn't make a lot of sense, at least superficially.

Comment: And you are not seeing any error(s) in the console?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing it to:

```
    $('form').submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
    $.post('/parts', function() {
            window.location.href = '/parts';
        });
    });
```

Comment: @JoeDoe remember not to remove **$(function() { ... })** from it. I removed them to make my code shorter and easier to read.

Comment: Yes, I left it there. Still nothing.

Comment: I think FF has a very complicated way of preventing the default action from bubbling.

Comment: @JoeDoe Try to debug your app on Firefox, and see if `e` has `cancelBubble` property. You'll have to set it to `true` to prevent browser from running default action on it.